# Amazon Redshift - Vacuum and Analyze details

Tags: amazon-redshift, vacuum

Is it possible to view the history of all vacuum and analyze commands executed for a specific table in Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the history of VACUUM  run using query history tables - `SVL_STATEMENTTEXT` etc.
[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) for more details.
Fair warning, these history tables only store data for last 15 days, so in the long run you might wanna take back ups.

You can also check the current sorted-unsorted blocks for a current table in Redshift, that gives a good idea of how the table data is stored.
[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) for more details.